# Java taxes class

Tags: java

So this code seems to work fine for what I'm asked to do but I feel like is a mess and want to figure out ways to clean it up a little nothing to advanced just maybe a for loop or if statement perhaps even for loop enhanced or even an Array. I feel like this code is too long and messy sort of like a spheggti code

this is for my computer science class I'm in.
here are the instructions.

> > Write a program that computes taxes due for a person with a filing status of single.  Include deductions, exemptions, and credits. Apply
> >     the tax rate to the income after applying the deductions and
> >     exemptions.  Then subtract credits from the tax due to get the final
> >     tax amount due.  Expected output sample is provided below.  Name your
> >     class  TaxReturn.   Income:               $85,500 Deductions:             $23,753
> >     Exemptions:                   $15,200
>
> Taxable Income:           $46,547
>
> Tax:                  $  7,667 Less Credits               $  5,000
>
> Tax Due:               $ 2,667
>
> • Exemptions = number of exemptions X $3,800 •    Taxable Income = Income
>   – deductions – exemptions •   Tax amount (see chart below) •  Tax Due =

Comment: I think this is better question to ask under code review, which deals with code style/cleanup. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of efficiency, the code is fine.

In terms of clearity, I'm doing that

```
if (/*something*/) {
    // do this here
}
```

instead of

```
if (/*something*/)
{
    // do this here
}
```

You can get rid of comments or make them shorter like that

```
final double TAXRATE_15PERCENT = 0.15;    // 15% tax
final double TAXRATE_28PERCENT = 0.28;    // 28% tax
```

instead of

```
// This is the tax rate percent on the tax 15%
final double TAXRATE_15PERCENT = 0.15;
```

This kind of shortening might make you code better looking. I dont know if these are what you are looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by "yo can combine two lines"? It makes it *much* less readable to have two statements on one line, as you've suggested. Are you sure this is what you mean?

Comment: I editted typo. You are right, it sometimes makes less readable but also shows less complicated. This is just suggestion, you dont have to do that way, it has both advantages and disadvantages, sometimes you have to select either way.

Comment: From Oracle's official ["Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language", section 7 - Statements](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#430): "Each line should contain at most one statement. Example: `argv++; argc--; // AVOID!`"

Comment: Also "it has both advantages and disadvantage" the only advantage I can see is that you're saving one byte of filesize for the `\n` character. The disadvantages include (a) easy to miss the code, (b) confusing - why is it there? (c) not really logically related, like `a++;b++;c++;d++;e++;` ... and those are just off the top of my head.

Comment: Ok, it looks like you are right, I shouldnt be mean about that

Comment: I get rid of that part

Answer (score 1):

you can start using a "taxBoundaries" class that keep information about tax class (rich, not rich etc. ) and write a method that, given income as imput, retrieves the right taxrate and tax boundary

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing object-oriented programming, and you consistently refer to a *noun* that you don't have a *class* for, your not doing object-oriented programming right.

```
public interface Tax {

  public double taxOn(double value);

}

/**
 *  This class returns tax by table lookup, much like the first 100K in an USA IRS 1040.
 */
public class TableTax {


}

/**
 * This class returns tax by formula, much like the tax for those making +$100K in a 
 * USA IRS 1040.
 */
public class CalculatedTax {

}
```

I count at least six tax rates in your program, and if you ever need to update it, you would have to rewrite *all* of the logic.  Good object oriented programming is *designed* to replace that which is *obviously* going to be replaced, typically by calling the replaceable component through an interface.

Then you could make the "TaxFactory" which takes an input and returns a "Tax".

```
public TaxFactory {

  public Tax getTaxFor(double value) {
    tax = // however you decide which tax to use.
    return tax;
  }

}
```

now your code really will look clean

```
double taxAmount = new TaxFactory().getTaxFor(earnings).taxOn(earnings);
```

--- Edited in response to need to use arrays and for loops ---

Ok, so let's say it's taxed 10% on the first 20,000, 15% on the next 20,000 and 17% on the next 40,000 and 20% on everything above that.

```
double balance = taxable_amount;
double tax_bracket[][] = {{0.10, 20000}, {0.15, 20000}, {0.17, 40000}, {0.20, Double.MAX_VALUE}};

double tax = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < tax_bracket.length; index++) {
  if (balance > 0) {
    if (tax_bracket[index][1] < balance) {
      // calculate fraction of tax for the entire bracket
      tax += tax_bracket[index][0] * tax_bracket[index][1];
      // deduct the taxed part of the balance
      balance -= tax_bracket[index][1];
    } else {
      // calculate fraction of tax for the remaining balance
      tax += tax_bracket[index][0] * balance;
      // the entire balance has been taxed
      balance = 0;
    }
  }
}
return tax;
```

Comment: Wow that looks really cool. Only thing is we haven't really covered Interfaces yet just got to the end of Arrays in this class. Is there a better way to write my while loop maybe using Arrays or a for loop?

Comment: @Shire True, and you do need to learn how to user Arrays and for loops, but for all problems, they aren't always the best solution.  I added a two dimensional array example, just so you can get some idea of one array based solution.  Also, keep in mind that while doubles are great and everything, there's _something_ you should know about them in reference to money.  Double and Float are only approximations of a real world value, so there's error in the approximation, and in a real world program, you would have to deal with the error (or use int and long, counting pennies).